# Is is possible to nest a counter within an ASCIIdoc macro?

Tags: macros, asciidoc

I use ASCIIdoc macros, and I would like to embedded counter in a substitution macro, but it doesn't work as expected.

source document:

```
:macro-with-counter: foo-{counter:id}

* {macro-with-counter}: bar-one
* {macro-with-counter}: bar-two
* {macro-with-counter}: bar-three
```

expected rendering with an incrementing counter:

- foo-1: bar-one
- foo-2: bar-two
- foo-3: bar-three

actual rendering:

- foo-1: bar-one
- foo-1: bar-two
- foo-1: bar-three

Is it possible to nest a counter in a substitution macro in ASCIIdoc?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
foo-id: 0

* foo-{counter:foo-id}: bar-one
* foo-{counter:foo-id}: bar-two
* foo-{counter:foo-id}: bar-three
```

Comment: This works, but it is not a nested macro with a counter. 

Here is a simple use case. I have a single requirements document that I would like to compile as a requirements document or a test document for printing. 

:test_doc:

ifdef::test_doc[]
:macro-with-counter: Req-{counter:id} Checked? [ ] 
endif::[]

ifndef::test_doc[]
:macro-with-counter: Req-{counter:id}
endif::[]

* {macro}: req 1
* {macro}: req 2
* {macro}: req 3

expected rendering:

* Req-1 Checked? [ ]: req 1
* Req-2 Checked? [ ]: req 2
* Req-3 Checked? [ ]: req 3

actual: the counter doesn't increment

Comment: Apparently the reply option is more limited in its formatting - sorry about the block above. @Anton, your solution works for some use cases, but it is not a nested macro. What if I wanted to define a fragment of text with a counter in a substitution macro in order to compile the same document for multiple purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: it is not possible to nest macros in ASCIIdoc. This implies a recursion capability that isn't there.